# GridLayout bigger than screen

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridLayout`, but the children set their `layout_width` to `match_parent`, and make it so that the `GridLayout` extends its size to outside the screen (see image).

How can I do to let the items `match_parent`, keeping the `GridLayout` inside the screen?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Buscar"
                    android:id="@+id/tvRecorrido"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <SearchView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/svBusqueda"
                    android:queryHint="@string/hint_buscar"/>    

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fecha"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:id="@+id/etFecha"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            </GridLayout>    

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_ver_horarios"
                android:id="@+id/buttonIniciarSesion"
                android:textColor="@color/azul"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="verHorarios"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need the GridLayout at all. You can replace the LinearLayout with a single RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ok, then show me an answer to acomplish what I am looking for: The label "buscar" must be centered vertically in connection with the searchview. Same with the label "fecha" in connection with the edittext. But the edittext and the searchview must be aligned vertically (start at the same X coordinate, although one is above the other one).

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what I ened up with to make your layout use only a single RelativeLayout (avoiding nasty nested layouts is better for performances).

The tricky part was to make the TextViews vertically aligned with their mating editable Views.
Solved by giving all Views the same fixed width (40 dp turned out to be quite a good value).

This is the result:

[image]

Note: Since I don't use your theme (nor Material Design - since I'm a FREE thinker and like to do things my way, ALWAYS), I used a background color for the parent layout.

This leaves a white border (didn't have the time and will to fix that).
You won't have this issue. Just remove it from the RelativeLayout.

---

This is the code I used (in the comments you'll find out how to restore your SearchView and your Button):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bdf"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRecorrido"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Buscar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
<!--    <SearchView -->
<!--        android:id="@+id/svBusqueda" -->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!--        android:layout_height="40dp" -->
<!--        android:queryHint="@string/hint_buscar" -->
<!--        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" -->
<!--        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" -->
<!--        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvRecorrido" -->
<!--    /> -->



<!--
    For my test project only, I replaced the SerachView (requires API Level 11)
    with an EditText (I support API Level 8+)
-->
<!-- You can simply remove my EditText (below) and uncomment your SearchView (above) -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/svBusqueda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:queryHint="This was: @string/hint_buscar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvRecorrido"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Fecha"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/svBusqueda"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFecha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvFecha"
        android:layout_below="@id/svBusqueda"
    />

<!--    <Button -->
<!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!--        android:text="@string/btn_ver_horarios" -->
<!--        android:id="@+id/buttonIniciarSesion" -->
<!--        android:textColor="@color/azul" -->
<!--        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" -->
<!--        android:onClick="verHorarios" -->
<!--        android:paddingLeft="8dp" -->
<!--        android:paddingRight="8dp" -->
<!--        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" -->
<!--        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" -->
<!--        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/etFecha" -->
<!--    /> -->



<!-- For my test project only, I removed: -->

<!--        android:textColor="@color/azul" -->
<!--        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" -->
<!--        android:text="@string/btn_ver_horarios" -->

<!-- I used fixed values in place of the string and the color resources -->
<!-- You can simply remove my Button (below) and uncomment yours (above) -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VER HORARIOS"
        android:background="#bdf"
        android:id="@+id/buttonIniciarSesion"
        android:textColor="#4af"
        android:onClick="verHorarios"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/etFecha"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but what if user changes the device's text size? (from device configuration). If the text appear to be larger than 40dp, they will wrap, and I dont want that. That's why I wanted to use a gridlayout (can't understand why can't I use that component, if its available for use...). Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Of course you can. I'm always looking for **optimizing** (and avoiding nested layouts is an optimizaion). If he user does **weird things**, that's not my business. He/she are aware that they are screwing up the system.

Comment: Of course you can :) but I am doing an App that may be used by elder people, and there is a chance that they use big text in their smartphones. That's why I am trying to anticipate (besides this is an app for my carreer tesis and need to handle this things). If you know a way to do what I am looking for, with grids or similar solutions, will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't get rid of grids, have a peek into `GridLayout` (root container).